# Where to divide an MVC project

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

My .NET MVC app was getting slightly horrid to look at, so I took the proactive step of splitting my project in two. Now I've got all code in one, all views / content in the other.

Here's my issue: is it better to split the project into stateless vs stateful, or code / non-code as I have done. I have no foreseeable reason to reuse the stateless repositories etc, but I'm unsure whether it would be good 'future proofing'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

code / non-code for sure... but within that there may be ways of further dissecting the code into more manageable pieces. Have a look at the Martin Fowler if you need more help with design patterns.